# How to put all react production build files in single level root folder without keeping directory tree in static

Tags: reactjs, build, npm-scripts, ipfs

This is my first time I am working with IPFS together with React.

Judging from the reactjs examples, the code to run the website itself does not different from non-IPFS-based website.

As per documentation of the hosting I use ([www.unstoppabledomains.com](http://www.unstoppabledomains.com)), in order to be compliant to IPFS, I need to have all files in same directory level.

The command npm run build produces default react directory structure with static folder and its child folders for css, js and media.

Therefore, how to achieve that all files, produced by build target, is in same level (a.k.a there is no folder static and no subfolders)?

Answer (score 0):

There's no requirement for any specific directory setup to use IPFS, you can structure your project however you see fit.

Are you seeing an error message or other problem?

Comment: Yes, the hosting I use does not support uploading folder structure and as per their documentation, it has to be same-leveled.

Comment: @HX_unbanned Mind linking to specific docs that say that? Sounds like a bug in unstoppabledomains' docs